# How to add post_type=value when editing that post type in the Wordpress admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query

So basically in The Wordpress Admin when you are editing a "post" you have a url slug like...

```
post.php?post=829&action=edit&classic-editor
```

I would like to know, is there a filter or way that I can add the post_type query arg to this url? Which would result in something like...

```
post.php?post=829&action=edit&classic-editor&post_type=product
```

I would like this to run for all post types (page, post, product, ...)

**Why:** I have a plugin that disables plugins from loading based on a string in the url.

**My Goal:** is to reveal the `post_type=value` in the url when editing a post, so that I can disable plugins from loading when editing post types that those plugins do not need to load on.

**Example:** when editing a portfolio post type, I do not need Woocommerce or its addons to load. So I would like to disable them when editing portfolio posts.

This is entirely for performance reasons of a potential mu-site I might offer publicly.

Thank you.

Comment: please explain, what your goal is with that additional arg..

Comment: @honk31ok. thank you. I updated my post with my why, goal, and an example...

Comment: You should be able to extrapolate the Post Type by Post ID `post`. It would be cached so there shouldn't be any additional database queries. See [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/). Even new posts should have a `global $post` object to work with.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thanks. Yes, but how would I filter that into the url is my question? Or did I misunderstand something of your comment? I was hoping there might be a built in filter of Wordpress to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go, i tested it in my current development and it works. it adds the post_type query parameter to all edit links, even on custom post types and also on the admin bar. this even works with preexisting query parameters and i also have other plugins currently running (f.ex. wpml).

```
function so370070_admin_url($url, $path)
{
    if (strpos($path, "post.php") !== false) :
        $post_type = get_post_type();
        if ($post_type) :
            $url = add_query_arg('post_type', $post_type, $url);
        endif;
    endif;

    return $url;
}

add_filter('admin_url', 'so370070_admin_url', 10, 2);
```

and as solved by yourself, here is the links for attachments:

```
function so370070_register_post_type_args($args, $post_type)
{
  if ($post_type == 'attachment') {
    //NOTE: This "_edit_link" arg is noted for Wordpress's internal use only
    //in /wp-includes/post.php around line 84
    //However, we are using a dveloper's filter to adjust it, so use accordingly
    //that you understand it may need tweaked if Wordpress itself makes changes
    //Overall it should be generally safe... no issues so far :)
    $args['_edit_link'] = add_query_arg('post_type', 'attachment', $args['_edit_link']);
  }

  return $args;
}

add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'so370070_register_post_type_args', 10, 2);
```

Comment: You might be able to use the `add_query_arg()` function too which may be safer.

Comment: thanks @Howdy_McGee, i altered the answer to your sugggestion

Comment: Thanks @honk31 and @ Howdy_McGee ! I was looking through the WP Core, and was coming along to trying some stuff, but you have solved it already. **Thanks!** This is awesome! I can really boost the speed now and have complete control of plugin loading in the admin.

Comment: @honk31 would you be able to see why this doesn't work on media attachment posts? It would be post_type=attachment I believe, but the post_type=attachment doesn't show, so maybe it needs to tap into another filter there? If you have time. I'm just in the dark about this kind of thing and I know it will take a much longer time, if at all to actually find a solution.

Comment: @EnterpriseBranding well first of, if does not work with attachment, since it will not pass the first IF statement, the url is not post.php but upload.php. i tried around a little but couldn't solve it for now, attaching query args to upload.php didn't do anything.. sorry

Comment: @honk31 ok. Well, upload.php is not a problem because that string of url is unique to target. Meaning, I can target "upload.php" for media because it does not use the string of  "edit.php". However, when editing a single attachment "post.php" is still the string of url used. So I was hoping to append the attachment query arg when editing single media files. I am going to play around with it shortly, so if I come up with something I will post it. Thanks! And thanks for getting me this far. I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP!

Comment: @honk31 I did figure this out, at least to what is missing. The post_type query arg works on attachments, but only from the "list view" of attachments, not the media library/grid view of attachments. See screenshot @ https://take.ms/OGnkL but I can't seem to find a filter for the "Edit more details" link in the media grid view for attachments. See screenshot @ https://take.ms/awqJdl ... would you be able to help with filtering that "Edit more details" link?

Comment: @EnterpriseBranding ah, good to see you figured it out with list view, since i couldn't get it to work with grid view. since in grid view the elements are not links, but list items with javascript events that take care of the pop up. the event is called 'imageEdit.open( 271, "37ba94da39" )', at least in list view. first argument is attachment_id, second is a ajax nonce? maybe [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/157007/10994) can be of help?

Comment: @honk31 ok. Thanks! I really appreciate it. And thanks again for the answer! What I am going to do is hide that "Edit more details" link with css, then generate the link I need through my framework https://github.com/wponion/wponion. Thanks!

Comment: @honk31 I found a solution. Generally not recommended because it filters an internal Wordpress arg, however it should be generally safe I think. I added it to a gist with screenshot in comments. If you feel it is worth it, you can add my solution/answer to your answer, but none the less it is here @ https://gist.github.com/EnterpriseBranding/1ae0885d28c44289db2b58ec6abe2b26

Comment: @EnterpriseBranding nice one! please try my modification, i add the parameter via `add_query_arg`, might be better than hardcoding the url..

Comment: @honk31 thanks! I updated the gist as well with the full code and descriptions and credits @ https://gist.github.com/EnterpriseBranding/1ae0885d28c44289db2b58ec6abe2b26 ... really really really appreciate it, because this has let me build something that can normally be done with Wordpress without greatly having performance and loading concerns. But now I can control which plugins are loading where in the admin, so the performance is even better than more common Wordpress installs.